# IDEA nodejs mocha tests are recognized, but run as code

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, mocha.js

In IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1, I have a large nodejs project with many NPM modules. Most of them contain `test` sub-dir with Mocha tests.  IDEA recognizes and runs tests (`describe() + it()`) for most projects just fine, showing a nice testing interface with run results, except for one. For one project, it recognizes the tests (shows green arrows on the right of `describe` and `it`), but when ran, it runs it as regular code with the node interpreter, which obviously fails.

How do I ensure the project's test is ran as Mocha?

P.S. When I added a "mocha" debug profile, it runs fine if i start the mocha run/debug profile by hand.

P.P.S.
I manage to solve it by editing `.idea/workspace.xml` - for some reason it contained this element. Deleting it made everything work fine. I hope there is a way to do this from UI.

`<configuration default="false" name="routeTest.js" type="NodeJSConfigurationType" factoryName="Node.js" path-to-node="project" path-to-js-file="routeTest.js" working-dir="$PROJECT_DIR$/server/test">
  <method />
</configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that the problem is caused by existing **Node.js** Run configuration with "JavaScript file" set to your mocha test file (`routeTest.js`). Explicitly created run configurations associated with current file have priority over the ones auto-generated from context. Deleting the configuration should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @lena, but I didn't create it - it somehow got created automagically. The only explicitly created run/debug configuration is still there, under Mocha, and it is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it was caused by [karma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma) dependency in `package.json`. Currently the only workaround is setting the initial mocha test run configuration manually then we can run tests by clicking icons.

Update:
It was caused by a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29183) in Idea and it is already fixed. Please note the last [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29183#commentDateGroup_27_2627808) if you use karma-mocha and mocha tests simultaneously.